# c++ assigning dynamic struct

Tags: c++, dynamic, struct

I really want to do the following:
(sorry about syntax, I have no idea how this is done)

```
struct Data {
   int var = 5;
} data;

struct Data2 {
    var;
} data2;

data2.var = data;

cout << data2.var.var; //prints 5
```

Basically I want to have a dynamic struct variable in a struct that can be given any struct as value and access it through the mains struct.

Please be nice. I really don't know how to explain it better and I really want to do this and been reading a lot yet haven't found any methods to do this.

Ps.
I DON'T want to do the following:

```
struct Data {
   int var = 0;
} data;

struct Data2 {
    data;
} data2;
```

I want it to be dynamic, that is, that I can change it any time during the program. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: Are you just trying to have a `Data` member inside a `Data2` instance?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you may (?) be asking about references:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    int & xref = x;

    std::cout << xref << "\n";

    x = 20;

    std::cout << xref << "\n";
}
```

That will print:

```
10
20
```

Underlying a reference is essentially a pointer, but it is one which can never be null...and notationally you don't have to "dereference" it.  Were you using pointers, the above would look like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    int * xptr = &x;

    std::cout << *xptr << "\n";

    x = 20;

    std::cout << *xptr << "\n";
}
```

Here they are applied to your example with minimal changes:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Data {
   int var;
};

struct Data2 {
    Data & var;
};

int main() 
{
    Data data = {5};
    Data2 data2 {data};

    std::cout << data2.var.var << "\n";

    data.var = 10;

    std::cout << data2.var.var << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Odds are "this isn't what you *actually* want" (you shouldn't usually be exposing member variables, much less member variables that are references to other variables).  And they shouldn't be all named `var`.  Etc.

Still, references are an integral part of the language and worth learning about.

*(Note: for brevity, you may omit the `return 0;`...only from main.  That's assumed, and legal in the standard; and you may omit its arguments.  But you must return an int.)*

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I want to have a dynamic struct variable in a struct that
>   can be given any struct as value and access it through the mains
>   struct.

You can emulate the effect of dynamic typing by using polymorphism. The following is a test example for your case.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct BaseDataStruct
{
    virtual int get_data() = 0;
};

struct Data : BaseDataStruct
{
    int var = 5;
    virtual int get_data() { return var;}
} data;

struct Data2 {
  BaseDataStruct* var;
} data2;


int main() 
{
    data2.var = &data;

    cout<<data2.var->get_data();

    return 0;
}
```

By using `BaseDataStruct` as an interface base class for all the structs which `Data2::var` is expected to point to you can achieve the "dynamic typing" behavior you are trying to get.

**Note:** I changed the `Data2::var` a to pointer to avoid object slicing. You will need to jump through many hoops to avoid that if you want to have it by value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use void pointer like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    int var;
}data;

struct Data2
{
    void *var;
}data2;

int main()
{
    data.var = 5;
    data2.var = &data;
    cout<<((Data *)data2.var)->var<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it is not safe because somtimes you can't make sure that other struct has member called `var` which may cause unexpected result.

Comment: He would need to know the type of the object he is pointing to to cast it. I am not sure if this gives him the dynamic typing behavior he expects.

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR**: C++ is statically typed, so what you want to do is against the spirit of thr language. However, if you really have to you can use void* in C and [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html) in C++

Now a bit more about void* (to know more about boost::any refer to its documentation).

void* is a pointer that holds a raw address in memory. This value beyond this address could be everything: float, int or your struct. Here is the usage example.

```
struct Data {
    int var = 5;
};

struct Data2 {
    void* var;
};

int main() {
    Data data;
    Data2 data2;
    data2.var = (void*)(&data);
    cout << ((struct Data*)data2.var)->var << endl;
}
```

If the concept of pointers is new for you you can read about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). Void pointers are explained there as well.